# How to compile Ubuntu webapps app userscript?

Tags: webapps

I've created a userscript(.user.js.in file) in `src` folder of `webapps-application`.So how can I compile it now?

Comment: why do you want to compile it? it's enough to put it in /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/SCRIPTNAME/, aside with it's manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Make file.

Here is the sample [Makefile.am file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~webapps/webapps-applications/trunk/view/head:/src/Makefile.am)

If you look at line number the 3 in `Makefile.am` file. All the users.js scripts that are placed under `src` directory will be picked.

You need to create the same structure showed in [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~webapps/webapps-applications/trunk/files/head:/) and follow the below commands to build

```
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install prefix=/usr
```

> Reference:
>
> 1. http://quickmediasolutions.com/blog/9/using-the-unity-web-api
> 2. http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~webapps/webapps-applications/trunk/files/head:/

Comment: Yeah,I have done that already but it didn't work.The official tutorial says that we need to create a file like 'anyname.user.js.in' in src folder.But they never explained what to do with it.Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the official tutorial page?

Comment: Here it is http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/unity/integrating-tumblr-to-your-desktop/